# How do you deal with local differences while merging your dev branch with master and back

Tags: git, merge, branch

In our small team each developer works in his own ("private") Git branch.
Every now and then they sync the master branch, then merge it with their own branch and subsequently the other way around to master, so that everything is in sync.

I have in my local branch certain typical changes in the code and certain scenarios that we don't want in the master branch and I find myself adding and removing etc. these code parts constantly.

So probaby I am doing something wrong. How do you deal with such a situation?

Comment: One simple option would be to `git stash` before you pull, then apply the stash afterwards.  Or, more simply, you may ignore the changes you made locally which you don't want to be part of the remote.

Answer (score 0):

There could be two workflows:

1. Work on a `devel` branch and keep making commits there.

   - git fetch -all
   - git rebase origin/master (on devel)
2. Save you changes using `git stash`

   - git stash save "my work description"
   - git pull
   - git stash pop stash{0}

I'd use the first workflow for daily use. `stash` is only useful for occasional use.